# How to map an object of getters to their value?

Tags: typescript

I have this function `applyObject` that I want to propertly type. The paramters to the function are of `T` and `V` where `V` is an object of functions:

```
type V = { [key: string]: <R>(t: T) => R };
```

and `T` is the type I want to feed across all the functions of `V` when applied. Is there any way to do this?

I'm thinking it's possible with a mapped type but I'm unsure. I'm thinking like this:

```
function applyObject<T, V extends { [key: string]: (t: T) => any }>(t: T, v: V) {
  return Object.entries(v).reduce((applied, [_key, func]) => {
    const key = _key as keyof V;
    applied[key] = func(t);
    return applied;
  }, {} as {[P in keyof V]: Invoke<V[P]>}); // `Invoke` doesn't exist
}

const applied = applyObject(
  { one: 1, two: 'something' },
  { a: t => t.one, b: t => t.two }
);

applied.a; // should give intellisense as number
applied.b // should give intellisense as string
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible, the problem is that even `V` is not well typed, I'm guessing you want to say that any function of `V` takes a `T` and can return any type, but the way you define it `R` is up to the caller not the function.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I removed `R` from the question. I'm not sure if it's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
type V<T, A> = {[K in keyof A]: (t: T) => A[K]};
function applyObject<T, A extends any>(t: T, v: V<T, A>): A {
  const ret = {} as A;
  for (const k in v) {
    ret[k] = v[k](t);
  }
  return ret;  
}

const applied = applyObject(
  { one: 1, two: 'something' },
  { a: t => t.one, b: t => t.two }
); // inferred as {a: number, b: string}
```

The idea is to express the `V` type in terms of the input object type `T`, and the type `A` of the intended return value of `applyObject()`.  The keys of `V<T,A>` are the same as those of `A`, and the values are functions from `T` to the appropriate property type of `A`.  And this definition lets you use [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) to type `applyObject()`.

(There's a little caveat here.  If you see, I defined the `A` parameter in `applyObject()` to be `A extends any`.  That shouldn't be necessary; every type extends `any` in TypeScript.  But without it, `A` gets inferred as `{a: any, b: any}` which isn't particularly useful.  I have no idea why `A extends any` fixes it, but it does.  Someone better acquainted with the nitty gritty of TypeScript type inference have any ideas?)

I also modified the implementation since it was easier for me to convince TypeScript that it was type-safe.  Feel free to use your own implementation, if you can make TypeScript happy or force it into silence.

Anyway, hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: you're a wizard

Comment: and I think typescript types the return of `Array.prototype.reduce` as the initial accumulator so `.reduce(/*...*/, {} as A)` might have worked

Comment: I just wanted to let you now how often I go back and reference this even months later--because I look back at this a lot. Thanks again!